# Как установить APT в snappy ubuntu core?

Tags: ubuntu, apt-get, apt

поставил на свою машинку **snappy ubuntu core** для разнообразия. теперь не могу использовать привычный apt. А без него -- как без рук. подскажите плиз, как его установить?

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте

To get some apps not snapped yet on my Ubuntu Core arm i used the classic snap:

```
sudo snap install classic --devmode --edge
```

then

```
sudo classic
```

then apt-get is available

источник: https://askubuntu.com/questions/902905/install-applications-in-ubuntu-core
https://askubuntu.com/questions/577105/is-there-a-way-to-add-repo-to-snappy-ubuntu-core